# How do I have the entered data go into the next line of a text file

Tags: java, text

I have a text file that has the date, name, description and amount.

```
10/10/2018, Gel, Hair Product, 2000.00
```

With the code I made, the user can enter a new line into the original text file:

```
public static void recordExpense(String filename)throws IOException{
    String expense = "";
    String date = "";
    String description = "";
    double amount = 0.0;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename,true)));
        date = readDate(); //user enters the date
        expense = readExpense(); //user enters the name of the expense
        description = readDescription(); // user enters the description of the expense
        amount = readAmount(); .//user enters how much it costs
        pw.println(date+", "+expense+", "+description+", "+amount);
        pw.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("The file could not be found");
    }
}
```

Instead of having the expected output like:

```
10/10/2018, Gel, Hair Product, 2000.00
11/10/2018, Comb, Stuff, 20.00
```

It would come out like this instead:

```
10/10/2018, Gel, Hair Product, 2000.0011/10/2018, Comb, Stuff, 20.00
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: So you want it to come out like the second example, with all of it in a straight line?

Comment: No he wants in the first

Comment: Nope, I need it to be the first example.

Comment: Your program is working and `println()` seems to failed to create a new line, try `print()`. Create a constant  `private static final String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");`and use `pw.print(date+", "+expense+", "+description+", "+amount+newLine);`.

Comment: If the file already exists, and you can't touch it, you'll have to read it first to check if it contains a blank line at the end or not. And then add the missing blank line first if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file obviously does not end with a newline. If you want to add a new text on a new line, you need to print this newline first and then print the text.

Replace:

```
pw.println(date+", "+expense+", "+description+", "+amount);
```

With:

```
pw.print(System.lineSeparator()+date+", "+expense+", "+description+", "+amount);
```

Comment: That will add blank lines to the file. It's also quite strange to use the line separator sometimes, and \n some other times.

Comment: @JBNizet My mistake, fixed.